# How to print output once using getopt with several commands in C

Tags: c, linux, unix, getopt

I have a C file, which reads user input and prints according to various commands.

For instance if I execute ./cat -n filename

then it prints numbers on each line

if I execute ./cat -e filename

then it prints $ on each line

So far its working fine, but when I execute both commands together such as ./cat -n -e filename then it prints a file two times because I have kept printf statement in both cases. However I want to print the output once only.

Here is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int flag = 0;

    char *cvalue = NULL;
    int index;
    int c;
    char buffer[256];
    int linecount=1;
    opterr = 0;
    FILE *file ;
    while ((c = getopt (argc, argv, "net")) != -1)
        switch (c)
        {
            printf("string %c",c);
          case 'n':

            printf("optind %d",optind);

            for (index = optind; index < argc; index++)
            {
                FILE *file;
                file = fopen(argv[index], "r" );
                //  printf("command %s",argv[1]);
                /* fopen returns 0, the NULL pointer, on failure */
                if(argc<=2)
                {
                    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin))
                    {
                        //it will print the user input with number
                        printf("\t %d %s", linecount, buffer);
                        //it will increase the variable by 1
                        linecount++;

                    }
                    printf("\n");
                    linecount=1;
                }

                if ( file == 0 )
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), file))
                    {
                        //it will print the user input with number
                        printf("\t %d %s", linecount, buffer);
                        //it will increase the variable by 1
                        linecount++;

                    }
                    printf("\n");
                    linecount=1;
                }

            }

            break;
          case 'e':
            for (index = optind; index < argc; index++)
            {
                int x;
                FILE *file;
                file = fopen(argv[index], "r" );
                //  printf("command %s",argv[1]);
                /* fopen returns 0, the NULL pointer, on failure */
                if ( file == 0 )
                {
                }
                else
                {
                    while ((x = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
                    {
                        //it will print the user input
                        if(x =='\n')
                        {
                            //It will add '$' at the end of each line
                            printf("$");
                        }
                        else if(x=='\r')
                        {

                            printf("$^M");
                        }
                        //it will print each line
                        printf("%c",x );
                    }
                }
            }


            break;
          case 't':
            for (index = optind; index < argc; index++)
            {

                FILE *file;
                file = fopen(argv[index], "r" );
                //  printf("command %s",argv[1]);
                /* fopen returns 0, the NULL pointer, on failure */
                if ( file == 0 )
                {
                }
                else
                {
                    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), file))
                    {

                        char *str =buffer;
                        while(*str){
                            switch(*str){
                                // case '\v': printf("\\v");break;
                                //  case '\n': printf("\\n"); break;
                              case '\t': printf("^I"); break;

                              default: putchar(*str);break;
                            }
                            str++;
                        }
                        //  printf("%s \n", buffer);


                    }
                }
            }


            break;
          default:
            abort ();
        }

    //printf ("aflag = %d, bflag = %d, cvalue = %s\n",
    // aflag, bflag, optarg);

    // for (index = optind; index < argc; index++)
    //printf ("Non-option argument %s\n", argv[index]);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The current output :

```
    1 #include<stdio.h>
         2
         3
         4
         5
         6
         7
         8      int main()
         9 {
         10     printf("hello");
         11
         12
         13
         14 getchar();
         15 return 0;
         16 }

#include<stdio.h>$
$
$
$
$
$
$
        int main()$
{$
        printf("hello");$
$
$
$
getchar();$
return 0;$
}$
```

Required Output:

```
1  #include<stdio.h>$
     2  $
     3  $
     4  $
     5  $
     6  $
     7  $
     8          int main()$
     9  {$
    10          printf("hello");$
    11  $
    12  $
    13  $
    14  getchar();$
    15  return 0;$
    16  }$
```

Comment: You should just set flags in your getopt loop and then act on these flags just once, after the loop.

Comment: @PaulR can you please give me an example? I understand that I should keep flags for each cases then at the end I check howmany flags are collected and print according to it. But the main problem is that I will have 7 commands then there will be heaps of condition.

Comment: That's what's required to achieve this. As a command gets more options it makes sense to define a structure which can easily be passed around the program. Should you need to add options, just alter the structure. Set the new option flag at the getopt stage of processing, the only other modifications required are where you'd already be inserting modifications.

Comment: @rhubarbdog If you can give me the code example that would be really appreciated.

Comment: @Ravi Vyas You may refer to this example: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Example-of-Getopt.html
As you can see, inside a getopt loop they just set some flags which define what should be done later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should separate the getopt loop from the business logic.

Here is an example how you could do it:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int flag = 0;

    char *cvalue = NULL;
    int index;
    int c;
    char buffer[256];
    int linecount=1;
    opterr = 0;
    FILE *file;
    int opt_n = 0, opt_e = 0, opt_t = 0;

    while ((c = getopt (argc, argv, "net")) != -1) {
        switch (c)
        {
            printf("string %c",c);
          case 'n':
            opt_n = 1; 
            break;
          case 'e':
            opt_e = 1; 
            break;
          case 't':
            opt_t = 1; 
            break;
        }
    }

    for (index = optind; index < argc; index++) {
        file = fopen(argv[index], "r" );
        if (file == NULL) {
            /* add code to print error message and exit */
        }
        while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), file))
        {
            if (opt_n) {
                // print line number
                printf("%4d ", linecount);
            }
            if (opt_t) {
                print_t(buffer);  /* you need to create this function */
            } else {
                printf("%s", buffer);
            }
            if (opt_e) {
                printf("$");
            }
            linecount++;
            printf("\n", linecount);
        }
        fclose(file);
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As Paul R commented, first check for the presence of the flags like this:

```
bool eflag = false;
bool nflag = false;
/* ... */

while ((c = getopt (argc, argv, "ent")) != -1) {
        switch (c) {
        case 'n':
                nflag = true;
                break;
        case 'e':
                eflag = true;
                break;
        /* ... */
        default:
                fprintf(stderr, "unknown option %c\n", c);
        }
}
```

Then you can process the input file, and react to the flags you have detected:

```
for (index = optind; index < argc; index++) {
        /* cut file opening stuff for brevity */
        while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), file) {
                if (nflag) {
                        printf("%d", linecount);
                }
                /* the other flags need char-wise processing */
                for (cvalue = *buffer; *cvalue != '\0'; cvalue++) {
                        switch (*cvalue) {
                        case '\n':
                                if (eflag) {
                                        printf("$");
                                }
                                printf("\n");
                                break;
                        /* check other characters */
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

This way, you can easily add other flags, or change the way you react on the flags.

And, much more important, you have only one occurence of the file handling code. Imagine, you have a bug in your file handling, in the old code you had to modify every occurence of it and likely forget some instances of said bug when fixing it. This way, you only need to fix it once and all cases are correct.

And finally, it outputs the processed file exactly once.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and help, however the other code worked.